# algorithm or c code implementation to find the smallest postive integer that has n or more divisors

Tags: c, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, performance

What is the efficient way to find the smallest integer with given or more number of divisors?
What i naively think is that find the number of divisors of the numbers starting from 2.
Sure this is not the best way.
Is there a way of guessing the starting point close to the answer? May be some relation between n and the number of divisors it can have.

Comment: Do the divisors have to be unique? ie does 4 have 1 or 2 divisors (2 and 2), excluding 1 and 4 of course

Comment: http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ron/pdfpapers/ordinarytest.pdf

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861994/algorithm-for-finding-smallest-number-with-given-number-of-factors

Comment: @Russ : yes they have to be unique

Answer (score 3):

If the prime decomposition of a number `n` is:
`n = p1^a * p2^b * p3^c` then the number of divisors is `(a + 1) * (b + 1) * (c + 1)`.

This is a hint for the solution.

The problem is not so simple as it seems.

I found interesting theorems and papers solving the problem:

http://oeis.org/A005179

http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ron/pdfpapers/ordinarytest.pdf

Comment: Good hint for the solution, but think about it. 30=2*3*5 has 8 divisors, by your formula you would get 2^7=128 as the smallest number.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath - I found interesting theorems and papers. I pasted them as comments to the question.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: nope, Petar Minchevs result is correct. 30=2*3*5 (recall that a,b and c are 1 in this case) and the formula comes to (1+1)*(1+1)*(1+1). It is a simple application of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @carlosdc - Thanks for the support, but I am wrong. For n = 8, I will give 2^(8 - 1) = 128, but Karoly's suggestion 2 * 3 * 5 has again (1 + 1) * (1 + 1) * (1 + 1) = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 divisors. Which is better than mine.

Comment: @Petar Minchev, I thought you were just proposing how to count the divisors, I didn't realize that was your algorithm for the whole problem.

Comment: @carlosdc - Well at first I thought it will work for the whole problem. Now I wrote it just as a hint(it is a part of the solution) and put links to the theorems and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using an adaptation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes to do this?  Go through possible divisors in turn, and add 1 to an accumulated total at the appropriate point.  For instance, when you reach 5, add 1 to the totals for 5, 10, 15 ...  It would not take a great modification of the code to do that.